# I changed default path, now I'm getting a subprocess error in miniconda. ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together

Tags: python, directory, dependencies, subprocess, miniconda

```
ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together
```

I just changed my default path within 'properties' to an external hard drive which I'm guessing is causing the issue.

I was trying to install a program called insightface when I encountered the error.

This is what I tried

```
(base) D:\Programs-AI> pip install -U insightface
```

This is what I got

```
Collecting insightface
  Using cached insightface-0.7.3.tar.gz (439 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Downloading setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting numpy
        Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
      Collecting cython
        Downloading Cython-3.0.9-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Downloading setuptools-69.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (821 kB)
         ---------------------------------------- 821.5/821.5 kB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Using cached numpy-1.26.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (15.8 MB)
      Downloading Cython-3.0.9-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (2.8 MB)
         ---------------------------------------- 2.8/2.8 MB 8.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Installing collected packages: setuptools, numpy, cython
      ERROR: Cannot set --home and --prefix together
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Any help is appreciated! I don't have the space to change my base directory back to my C drive so I'm gonna have to figure this out in order to get any new programs

Honestly, I'm very new to this all. I just copied all of my programs from my SSD to my external hard drive and changed the path within windows so they could be accessed there because I was out of space on my SSD. I just did that today so that could that cause any issues?

I also have no idea what the best terminal for downloading pip packages is. I was using miniconda today but I've used powershell and tried to use VS Code. I've been on a downloading rampage recently and have been tinkering and learning a lot.